# How to reduce the use of PermGen space in Grails

Tags: grails, memory-management, groovy, spring-security, grails-plugin

in my Grails application using the Spring Security Core plugin for authentication. I am facing a serious problem with that because my application took 21 seconds to lift the Tomcat was carrying 43/2 after installation.

So far so good, but began to occur error 'PermGen Error' memory error Tomcat server. Before it was 64 and Aug is 256 so that the error does not crash my app so often.

I wonder whether you know some plugin configuration in order to reduce the incidence of this error or some method to effect the release of this cache because the number of users is increasing and if you can not solve it unfortunately have to leave the plugin I seems to be an excellent choice for application security.

Someone could tell me if the amount of plugins used in an application interference has this memory?

Comment: Why do you think it's because of Spring Security Core? I always having same issue, even with basic Spring MVC app.

Comment: Right, this has nothing to do with Spring Security.

Comment: I figured it was the Core Security because of the lag time after installation, but do not know what causes the excessive use of this memory. Does anyone know any method to reduce its use? The number of users logged into the system influence the permgen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PermGen is a part of memory to store the static components of your app, mostly classes. Literally it will not be affected by either the amount of users or logs associated with user activities, which consumes heap space instead.

To reduce PermGen storage, you have to check your code, redesign those algorithms which contains unnecessary/redundant objects and operations, and consolidate variables and functions if possible. Generally speaking, simplified code will produce smaller executable files. That's the way you save the PermGen space.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of Tomcat permgen more than others.  There was a minor version in the 6 line that I couldn't every get to reliably stay running.  And even with the latest versions you still need to tweak your memory settings.  I use the following and it works best for me.  I still get them now and again, especially if I'm doing a lot of runtime compiling.  In production, it is a non-issue because all the development overhead of grails isn't there.

> -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=512m -Xms256m -Xmx1024m

Comment: Hello Gregg, what I'm wondering is how to reduce the use of PermGen in the application to not have to further increase the amount. But thanks for your intention to help me!